# Вывод значения битового поля в шестнадцатеричном виде

Tags: c++

Есть необходимость вывести значение битового поля в шестнадцатеричном виде.

Объявил класс:

```
class Bin // двоичное представление
{
    unsigned char m_bin0 : 3;
    unsigned char m_bin1 : 3;
    unsigned char m_bin2 : 3;
    unsigned char m_bin3 : 3;
    
public:
    
    void Show(int a);
};
```

Определил метод:

```
void Bin::Show(int a)
{
    m_bin0 = a;
    m_bin1 = a;
    m_bin2 = a;
    m_bin3 = а;

    std::cout << std::bitset<8>(m_bin0)<< std::endl; // в двоичном виде
    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(m_bin1) << std::endl; //в шестнадцатеричном виде
    std::cout << std::осt << static_cast<int> (m_bin2) << std::endl;//в восьмеричном виде
    std::cout <<static_cast<int>(m_bin3) << std::endl;// в десятичном виде
}

Bin b;
b.Show(5)
```

Все значения,кроме первого, выводятся в десятичном виде. Подскажите в чём причина?

Comment: Сдвигаете вправо, накладываете маску и печатаете (и никаких классов не нужно)

Answer (score 3):

Что hex, что oct, а 5 — оно и есть 5, что вы хотите? 3 бита — это максимум 7, во всех системах счисления >7 одинаково.

Если вас интересует *префикс* — ну, там, `0x` в 16-ричной или `0` в восьмеричной — то их вы должны выводить самостоятельно, явно указав необходимость этого (спасибо EOF) с помощью [`showbase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/showbase).

Comment: Спасибо. Отсутствие префикса меня и смутило.

Comment: [`showbase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/showbase)

Comment: @EOF Спасибо за подсказку, я уже и забыл, что такое есть...